# CiviEvent Participant Import

Tags: civievent, import

I have about 4,500 rows of participant that I would like to import.  In each row is a column for the  CiviCRM internal ID and columns for the requisite information about the event.

When I upload the CSV file about 400 rows are imported and for each of the other rows I get this error "Matching Participant record not found for Participant ID 10180. Row was skipped." Of course the ID number changes for each row.

I have cross-checked several rows and the IDs are valid.

The file is a CSV file so Excel formatting should not make a difference but I tried changing the field format and a few other things in Excel. Nothing has worked.

There are many duplicates in the list but not 4,000.  I have the duplicate setting set to update.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I re-ran the import with skip for duplicates and it worked perfectly.  For my case this fixed the problem.

-Josh

Answer (score 0):

After an import the failed rows are included in a new CSV file which you could download. That file contains the errors and per row why it failed.

It could be basicly something as invalid e-mail address e.g.

Comment: The error is "Matching Participant record not found for Participant ID 10180. Row was skipped." The 10180 is changed for each of the CiviCRM ID's. I am sorry if I was not clear with this.

Comment: The error is caused because you on duplicate setting set to update. Your participant id column should not contain the civicrm contact id but the participant id.